# How to make a type part of another type? (Java)

Tags: java

This question isn't worded the best, but essentially I created some classes that can be used as types called Dog, Cat, Whale, etc. I also made another class that could take in a pet. How would I make classes like dog, cat, etc. belong to the pet type?

Comment: What do you mean by "belong to the pet type"? I can think of at least two ways to interpret that sentence

Comment: I mean essentially what it means. I want different otherwise unrelated classes to be part of a pet class. So a method that takes in pet could take in dog, cat, etc.

Comment: "it means what it means" is a tautology

Comment: You could make an object called an animal, and then an interface called pet, which will allow some animals (probably not a while, unless you're aquaman) to be pets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html). In Java, you use the `extends` keyword in the class definition to make one class extend another.

For example:

```
public class Dog extends Pet { ...
```

Comment: Also, who keeps a whale as a pet? ;)

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. Edit : No one (hopefully) thats why I am not extending pet for the whale class.